# <a> Tag Doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a code which has two  tags. The first one doesn't work while the second one works. Why? Here is my code:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="/logo.png" height="150" width="300">
</div>
<div id="home">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="/home.png" height="95" width="95">
        <br>
        <b>HOME</b>
     </a>
</div>
<div id="news">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="/news.png" height="95" width="95">
        <br><b>NEWS</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is my page's CSS:

```
            #form{
                padding:2px;
                margin:0 auto;
                background:rgba(110,110,110,0.1);
                width:600px;
position: relative;
    left: 0px;
top: -230px;
            }
#home {
position: relative;
    left: -30px;
top: -145px;
}
#news {
position: relative;
    left: 80px;
top: -261px;
}
#logo {
position: relative;
    left: -200px;
}
#vwlogo {
position: relative;
    right: -620px;
top:-200px;
}
```

Please resolve this. I should really continue my work.

Comment: What happens? What should happen?

Comment: What actually is not happening? Where should the link refer to? Your HTML seems to be valid :)

Comment: What happens is that the link pressed doesn't redirect to mywebpage.com/blah.html# as its supposed to.

Comment: You know that # is referring to the current page?

Comment: Yes but I want it to go to the current page + # in the URL, as the second link does.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that when I get my mouse over the text in the first link, it doesnt change as it does when you get it over other links.

Comment: Show the CSS. My money is on the CSS. Absolutely positioned #logo, badly designed ::befores or ::afters, misapplied z-indexes etc.

Comment: I put your source in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/cowtdvc2/), but it doesn't have the issue. (It does have other issues though...)

Comment: @MrLister here is full page code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Sw39bib2

Comment: @geotsak Ah. In the full page, it's clear what the problem is: the #news div overlaps the #home div. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/cowtdvc2/1/) is a fiddle of the situation. And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/cowtdvc2/2/) is one where I gave the #news div a solid background, so you can see where the problem lies. Do you really need to have everything positioned relatively?

Comment: @MrLister yes because i want them exactly at spots i positioned them.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand where the second link should be directed, but I think that is something.

```
<div id="news">
    <a href="#news">
        <img src="/news.png" height="95" width="95">
        <br><b>NEWS</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't get it I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any issues with it. Try a different link to a different site or a different page. # keeps you on the same page so try sending it else where

Answer (score 0):

If you use # you can navigate inside the page, for example check the content links in this site:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

They look like this

```
<a class="tocxref" href="#h-12.1.1">Visiting a linked resource</a>
```

If you use without anchor you can navigate to any site for example

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

please try this code for example

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJEf2pg34Ls3yL7gvw-XYkVGvfgXb3_4fW8fyF1kfNYGPxyuoiuecq0VqQ" height="150" width="300">
</div>
<div id="home">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://www.google.com.ar/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="95" width="95">
        <br>
        <b>HOME</b>
     </a>
</div>
<div id="news">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://www.google.com.ar/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="95" width="95">
        <br><b>NEWS</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

if you remove the target="_blank" you will be redirected to the site you need in href

Comment: Didn't work. Also I forgot to mention that when I get my mouse over the text in the first link, it doesnt change as it does when you get it over other links.

Comment: please try with this sample code I edited in my answer and tell me if it worked the way you expected.